# Generating Keys for AWS Load Balancer Server, Need to know server type

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS Load Balancer Server Type
I am installing an SSL certificate against the AWS Load Balancer.  I have paid for a wild card cert with GoDaddy.com  .  In the SSL acquisition steps GoDaady, they ask to identify which type of server the CERT will be installed for,  I don't see AWS Load Balancer but I do see others such as Apache, Tomcat, IIS cPanel and many others.   I have search for the type in many queries and do not see the answer.     Anyone know which option I need to select???

Much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

I have had no problem using Godaddy certs for apache.  You will need to use openssl to convert them to .pem format.